# flutter : how to pass data to my php page with video

Tags: php, flutter, dart

i need to pass data with video that i wan upload but i don't know how to do that just like these data i need to pass it with the video to the php page

```
var data = {
      "fileInput": videoFile.path,
      "titleInput": titleController.text,
      "descriptionInput": descriptionController.text,
      "privacyInput": selectedCategorise.value,
      "categoryInput": listcategory.map((e) => {e['name']}),
    };
```

I know how to pass it on without a video like this function i pass the email and password

```
`signin() async {
    var formdata = formstatesignin.currentState;
    if (formdata.validate()) {
      formdata.save();
      var data = {"email": email.text, "password": password.text};
      var url = "http://10.0.2.2/mobtech2/login.php";
      var response = await http.post(url, body: data);
      var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (responsebody['status'] == "success") {
        savePref(responsebody['username'], responsebody['email'],
            responsebody['id']);
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("homepage");
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
    } else {
      print("Not vaild");
    }
  }`
```

this is the function that i wan pass data to it

```
`Future uploadVideo(File videoFile) async {
    var uri = Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2/videoTube/file_upload.php");
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

    var multipartFile =
        await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("video", videoFile.path);
    request.files.add(multipartFile);
    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
      print(value);
    });
    //final response = await http.post(uri, body: data);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("Video uploaded");
    } else {
      print("Video upload failed");
    }
  }`
```

this code for class processing in php

```
`<?php

include "config.php";

if (!isset($_POST["video"])) {
    echo "No video sent to page";
    exit();
}

// 1) create file Uplaod Data
$videoUploadData = new VideoUploadData(
                            $_FILES["video"], 
                            $_POST["titleInput"],
                            $_POST["descriptionInput"],
                            $_POST["privacyInput"],
                            $_POST["categoryInput"],
                            "REPLACE-THIS"    
                        );
// 2) Process video data (upload)
$videoProcessor = new VideoProcessor($con);
$wasSuccessful = $videoProcessor->upload($videoUploadData);

?>`
```

this code for class VideoUploadData in php

```
`<?php
class VideoUploadData{

    public $videoDataArray, $title, $description, $privacy, $category, $uploadedBy;

    public function __construct($videoDataArray, $title, $description, $privacy, $category, $uploadedBy) {
        $this->videoDataArray = $videoDataArray;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->description = $description;
        $this->privacy = $privacy;
        $this->category = $category;
        $this->uploadedBy = $uploadedBy;
    }
}
?>`
```

this code for class VideoProcessor in php

```
`<?php

class VideoProcessor{

    private $con;
    private $sizeLimit = 500000000;
    private $allowedTypes = array("mp4", "flv", "webm", "mkv", "vob", "ogv", "ogg", "avi", "wmv", "mov", "mpeg", "mpg");
    public function __construct($con) {
        $this->con = $con;
    }

    public function upload($videoUploadData) {

        $targetDir = "uploads/videos/";
        $videoData = $videoUploadData->videoDataArray;

        $tempFilePath = $targetDir . uniqid() . basename($videoData["name"]);

        $tempFilePath = str_replace(" ", "_", $tempFilePath);

        $isValidData = $this->processData($videoData, $tempFilePath);

        if (!$isValidData) {
            return false;
        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($videoData["video"]["tmp_name"], $tempFilePath)) {

            $finalFilePath = $targetDir . uniqid() . ".mp4";

            if (!$this->insertVideoData($videoUploadData, $finalFilePath)) {
                echo "Insert query failed";
                return false;
            }

        }
    }

    private function processData($videoData, $filePath) {

        $videoType = pathInfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if (!$this->isValidSize($videoData)) {
            echo "File too large. Can't be more than" . $this->sizeLimit . " bytes";
            return false;
        }

        else if (!$this->isValidType($videoType)) {
            echo "Invalid file type";
            return false; 
        }

        else if ($this->hasError($videoData)) {
            echo "Error code: " . $videoData["error"];
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    private function isValidSize($data) {
        return $data["size"] <= $this->sizeLimit;
    }

    private function isValidType($type) {
        $lowercased = strtolower($type);
        return in_array($lowercased, $this->allowedTypes);
    }
    private function hasError($data) {
        return $data["error"] != 0;
    }

    private function insertVideoData($uploadData, $filePath){}

}

?>`
```

Comment: you mean you want to upload a video file to server with a PHP backend?

Comment: I actually know how to upload a video to server with php as backend but also wan upload other data with it such as (title and description and category and privacy ) in the same function

Answer (score 1):

yes you can upload a video with discription like name and title use [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package

this is an example i use to upload a video with some discription to my server backend use the MultipartFile
when you use the function _upload(video1) i pass the video as an argument but you can do it other way if you want i also set the progress indicator for the video upload progress.

```
    // create listing,post and upload video to the server

  void _upload(video1) async {

    // get variables from shared preferences
    token = await SharedPreferencesProvider.getUserToken();
    userId = await SharedPreferencesProvider.getUserId();

    // api to upload video
    // Post a video to 
    var url = 'https://example.com/api/v1/video';
    var video1Path;
    if (video1 == null) {
      return;
    } else {
      video1Path = await MultipartFile.fromFile(video1.path);
    }

    FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
      "title": title,
      "products": "1",
      "description": description,
      "category_id": categoryId,
      "category_name": categoryName,
      "longitude": _longitude,
      "latitude": _latitude,
      "video1": video1Path,
    });

    Dio dio = new Dio();
    dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token";
    dio.post(url, data: data, onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
      setState(() {
        _isUploading = true;
        // show a progress %
        progressString ='uploading :' + ((sent / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
        if ( ((sent / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) == '100'){
          progressString = 'Saving...';
        }
        //progressString = ((sent / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
      });

    }).then((response) async => {
      setState(() {

        progressString = DemoLocalizations.of(context).uploadCompleted;
      }),
      print(response),

      //after successful product post we redirect to(Main page)
      goHome()
    })
        .catchError((error) => print(error));
  }
```